# Найти выход из лабиринта, размеры которого не известны

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Через запрос к API возвращаются 8 ячеек вокруг робота, значения которых могут быть Wall, Exit или Empty. Робот может сделать шаг в любом из этих направлений.

как разработать алгоритм, который будет находить выход из лабиринта?

p.s. выход из лабиринта в большинстве случаев где-то в центре, и недалеко от робота

Comment: выход обязательно с краю лабиринта или может быть и в центре лабиринта?

Comment: Ну, например, так. 1) Запоминать известное (строить карту). 2) На очередном шаге делать ход в направлении Exit, если его местоположение известно. 3) Если местоположение неизвестно - двигаться по кратчайшему маршруту к ближайшему Empty (если таких несколько - выбрать любой). 4) Если ни одно Empty не достижимо, кричать "Помогите-спасите!!!"...

Comment: @Akina ну это похоже на поиск в глубину :)

Comment: @tym32167 ?? по-моему, близко не лежало.

Comment: Алгоритм правой руки? На каждом перекрёстке поворачивать в сторону, "ближайшую" к правой.

Comment: Я знаю, как решать Вашу задачу, но я не буду тратить время на то чтобы расписать алгоритм, до тех пор пока не увижу Ваших попыток справиться с этой простейшей задачей самостоятельно.

Comment: @Akina ну так `Если местоположение неизвестно - двигаться по кратчайшему маршруту к ближайшему Empty (если таких несколько - выбрать любой)` - это по моему оч хорошо подходит к поиску в глубину. Смотрим текущий узел - если есть рядом с ним не посещенный узел - переходим, если нет - идем назад к последнему известному непосещенному узлу

Comment: @МихаилМуругов я тоже хотел это посоветовать, но есть как минимум 2 случая, где это не саботает - если выход в центре или если игрок гуляет по периметру острова в центре лабиринта :)

Comment: @tym32167 Вы правы. Эти случаи не учёл.

Comment: @tym32167 Поиск в глубину - это в дереве. То, что лабиринт окажется деревом - маловероятно.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов *Эти случаи не учёл* ?? Двигаться надо не вдоль стенки, а вдоль известных клеток. Тогда в обоих этих случаях выход будет найден.

Comment: @Akina поиск в глубину - это в графе. Граф может быть представлен по разному. Лабирит - это набор положений и переходов между ними, что, по сути, является определением графа.

Comment: @Akina `Двигаться надо не вдоль стенки, а вдоль известных клеток` не всё так просто :) так можно легко попасть в тупик и не выйти.

Comment: @tym32167 *так можно легко попасть в тупик и не выйти.* То есть мы в тупике, Empty поля есть, но не рядом - и мы, как дураки, стоим и не знаем куда податься... *поиск в глубину - это в графе.* Не в каждом графе. А только в дереве. В циклическом графе поиск в глубину не определён. Если не сказать - невозможен. И уж точно он невозможен для несвязного графа.

Comment: @Akina `То есть мы в тупике, Empty поля есть, но не рядом - и мы, как дураки, стоим и не знаем куда податься` - именно! [Поиск в глубину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83) - отлично ложится в граф с любым количеством циклов. Вы, вероятно, путаете поиск в глубину с чем то другим.

Comment: @Akina для несвязного графа поиск в глубину тоже пишется без проблем, но в случае лабиринта граф строится только из достижимых вершин, то есть  граф будет связный

Comment: @tym32167 *Вы, вероятно, путаете поиск в глубину с чем то другим.* Нет, не путаю. Поиск в глубину позволяет, кроме всего прочего, получить уровень (глубину) каждого узла, а также узнать количество промежуточных узлов между начальным и заданным (и при этом не выполнять полный обход, достаточно достигнуть целевой вершины).

Comment: @Akina вы говорите термины, которые мне неизвестны (я про уровень/глубину узла), я с удовольствием из изучу, если вы мне дадите ссылочку где по про это почитать. То же самое про невозможность поиска в глубину в графе с циклами. Также мне не понятно, где мы сйечас в дискуссии - вы сейчас согласны, что можно лабиринт считать связным графом и что поиск в глубину поможет найти выход, если он достижим, и что ваше предложение изначальное очень на это и похоже?

Comment: @tym32167 1) Да, лабиринт есть связный граф, если в нём заведомо можно найти выход. 2) Да, если считать, что на не-дереве поиск в глубину существует, то он поможет. 3) Похоже лишь отчасти - мой алгоритм не сохраняет пройденный путь, и в нём не определено понятие возврата.

Comment: @Akina ну, сохранение пути - этопросто деталь реализации, поиск в глубину по умолчанию только отмечает пройденные узлы, чтобы отличать из от не пройденных, что, в принципе, тоже деталь реализации (в дереве, например, этого делать и не надо вовсе). Я просто вот по этой фразе `двигаться по кратчайшему маршруту к ближайшему Empty` подумал, что вы имеете ввиду ближайший непосещенный узел, а раз есть понятие непосешенного узла, значит есть и посещенные, то есть есть отметки, какой узел был посещен, а какой нет. Если вы имели ввиду не это, а что то другое, то я неверно понял ваш алгоритм.

Comment: @tym32167 *сохранение пути - это просто деталь реализации* В приведённой Вами ссылке есть фрагмент "а после возвращаемся и продолжаем перебирать рёбра", который является существенным элементом алгоритма. Я лично не знаю, как его (возвращение) выполнить, если не запоминать маршрут - ибо неизвестно, куда и по какому пути собственно возвращаться. *подумал, что ... есть отметки, какой узел был посещен, а какой нет.* Это так, но пометка узла как посещённого не является отличительным признаком поиска в глубину. Кроме того, изначальная задача имхо предполагает, что узлы обнаруживаются по мере поиска.

Comment: @Akina всё верно, при поиске в глубину вы только сохраняете информацию как вы попали в текущую ячейку. То есть у вас есть маршрут как из самого начала вы оказались здесь. То есть это для текущей ячейки, а не для любой ячейки. Если вы под запоминанием маршрута имели ввиду это - то да, он созраняется. И итеративном варианте для этого используется стек, в рекурсивном - собственно, стек вызовов, то есть рекурсия.

Comment: @Akina В вашем случае вы, если оказались в тупике, предлагаете искать ближайшую непосещенную ячейку, которая по сути и находится на пути назад. То есть вы этот путь назад просто найдете другим способом. Но робот пойдет точно также, как пошел бы при поиске в глубину. И да, узлы строятся по мере обхода, и это никак не мешает поиску в глубину.

Comment: [Волновой алгоритм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Ли). Он описывается/упоминается едва ли не в каждой книге по разработке игр.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91035/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб шах и мат, я опять вылетел с дискуссии :( Есть ли возможность бросать обсуждение в чат, если там никто хотя бы часа 3-4 не отвечаат? А то сходил на обед и вот сюрприз

Comment: @tym32167, можно и вообще не перемещать в чат, можно и позже. Обычно я стараюсь после пары часов с последнего сообщения это делать, но иногда тяга к уменьшению модераторской очереди проверок просто неодолима( И у вас, по идее, должна быть возможность в чате писать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня чат заблочен рабочим фаерволом, то есть с работы я могу зайти в чат только через мобильный интернет, что будет для меня платно. Потому перенос любой моей дискуссии в чат создает мне проблемы.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я бы даже добавил платно и ооочень меделенно :(

Comment: @tym32167, ммм, сложная проблема... Я даже не знаю что тут можно сделать... Разве что стараться в процессе дискуссии удалять уже не нужные комменты и/или переносить их в чат. Тогда тревога в модераторской очереди будет, но в чат мы перемещать не будем, т.к. немного комментов - нормально. Возможно стоит так поступать. Запомнить же кому именно можно в чат переводить обсуждения а кому нет у нас вряд ли выйдет. Давайте пока верну комменты в качестве исключения)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov волновой, он же на поиске в ширину основан, а тут API и робот, робот же не сможет прыгать по краю волны, он только с текущей клетки на соседнюю может.

Comment: @tym32167 - хм, согласен. ЗЫ: робот может выпустить стаю маленьких летающих дронов, которые найдут для него путь _волной_. :)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov мне нравится эта идея :)

Answer (score 0):

предлагаю решение: принцип ходьбы вдоль правой стены.

1. идешь в любом направлении пока перед роботом не будет стена
2. Поворачиваешся так что бы стена была справа
3. и делаешь ход вперед
4. проверяешь что справа есть стена. Если стены справа нет - поворачиваешь направо.

и дальше циклишь 3 и 4 пока не выйдешь с лабиринта (я хз как это должно у тебя проверятся)

рано или поздно робот с лабиринта выберется.

Исключением являются лабиринты с закольцованными коридорами - там даный робот просто попадет в кольцо и начнет ходить по кругу вдоль правой стены.

---

Для прохождения лабиринта с кольцами - нужно строить "пиксельную карту". И выходить из кольца если таковое было замечено. А потом снова врубать алгоритм правой стены идя туда, где карта была неразведанной.

Усложнять наперед алгоритм не советую. Лучше усложняй только по мере надобности.